# Video is not playing in web view Android TV

Tags: android, video, google-tv, television

I am trying to make an application for Android TV where my use case is very simple. I want to display a content to user and when the user clicks a web view opens and a normal mp4 video (URL) loads.

However it does not start playing in Android TV, it straight away call the `onPageFinished()` and close the web view screen. It works well in Fire TV.

Do we have to include any other method to play it?

[Link I am trying to play](http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4)

Comment: use video view for that

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I need Webview for specific things

Comment: then use the HTML5 Video element in HTML the webview will handle the HTML Like a browser would because it is a browser. load a video player from a html file in the assets folder referencing the file you specified

Comment: I have tried that as well. even we placed a local file in the asset with a html and tried it however its not working!! any other idea!!!